# How to receive NDR notification from microsoft using node mailin?

Tags: node.js, email, email-bounces

I am using node mailin to receive mail at port 25, and today I  am now listening to 465 and 587 but, even though I can receive email from Gmail and normal email accounts , I am not receiving post delivery  bounces, in the past I was using Cpanel default email address routing to pipe the incoming messages, but I needed to change it to nodejs, what could be wrong?

I have been monitoring and I receive the NDR properly from multiple sources, except from microsoft (But messages coming from regular user accounts come through), I am not sure if it is like microsoft uses a different port that 25, 465 or 587 just for NDR notifications, does anybody know what could be the issue? thanks!

I tried receiving mail at my own node mailin server, and I expected to receive NDR from microsoft about bounced emails but I dont get any email